# How to associate Boost Spirit parsed entities with their location in input stream?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Boost Spirit library permits to [Track the Input Position While Parsing](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/tracking-the-input-position-while-parsing/). This mechanism allows informing about location of a parser error during parsing.

I'd like to preserve original location for all parsed entities together with them for future use. (For example, AST semantic verification.) What would be the recommended way to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the position of all entities you might be better off using a lexer, which produces tokens optionally carrying positional information about the matched input (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964228/boost-spirit-lex-qi-error-reporting)). If a lexer is not an option you might utilize the new `on_success()` construct (available in SVN or starting with Boost V1.47), which works similarily to `on_error()`, except that your supplied handler will be invoked on a successful parse of the rule it is associated with. The the conjure example to see how it works.