# Can't Build Boost Spirit Example conjure2

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost (1.77) spirit qi and lexer.  The error handler expects a stream of characters but I am passing it a stream of tokens, resulting in garbled error messages.

I believe that the thread below points to a solution:

[Boost.Spirit: Lex + Qi error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964228/boost-spirit-lex-qi-error-reporting)

In the comments there, @hkaiser writes:

> Just an update: the example has been renamed in SVN to conjure2.

I just took a look at conjure2. In an attempt to understand what the program does, I open main.cpp and read the comments, all I find is this:

> Not a calculator anymore, right? :-)

What is that supposed to mean?

I tried to compile the program and it fails with:

```
"error C2516: 'boost::phoenix::evaluator::impl<const Expr&, 
boost::phoenix::vector2boost::mpl::true_,
boost::phoenix::is_nullary,boost::proto::envns_::empty_env>::result_type': 
is not a legal base class"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked their bugtracking system? Sounds like a documentation bug to me.

Comment: "I tried to compile the program and it fails with" - how?

Comment: I tried myself and it start failing somewhere between boost 1.69 and 1.75; it's not a documentation bug but a bug probably introduced by a change in Phoenix or a utility library. It should be reported upstream.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to put this at the top of lexer_def.hpp:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>
```

That should define the missing expression template operators that prevent the lexer semantic actions from compiling.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering. I noticed your find on the mailing list. That was tricky to find, thanks for contributing! Maybe now you'll have enough "karma" (we call it reputation :)). Cheers

Comment: I am a refugee from reddit :) Thank you for confirming the problem on your side, Cheers